Nginx one client always gets 503 and the error is never logged
Why would nginx be not logging the request for some failed requests?
eg There are 2 clients x.x.x.1 and y.y.y.2 both hitting the exact same URL on my site: "/foo/bar".  In the logs I see the success and most of the failed requests:
x.x.x.1 [date] GET /foo/bar 200
x.x.x.1 [date] GET /foo/x 404
x.x.x.1 [date] GET /foo/testing_503_response 503

The other client is getting a 503 for /foo/bar. I would expect to see this 503 in the logs but instead there is nothing logged at all
y.y.y.2 [date] GET /foo/bar 503 # this does not get logged

Why would some errors not be logged in nginx? I have confirmed by checking my firewall that requests from both clients are being received, and passed on to the VM.
My .conf is quite simple:
server {
  listen 443 default_server ssl;
  server_name api.example.com;
  ssl_certificate   /etc/ssl/example.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key   /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
}

Also - if I create an endpoint that always returns 503, then hit it myself or from client 1, I see it is logged correctly:
127.0.0.1 [date] GET /foo/testing_503_response 503

If I hit this test endpoint from the 2nd client, there is nothing logged.  The firewall correctly shows the request came through.
Client 2 is actually getting a 503 with no logging for everything eg /foo/x should be a 404

Most likely client 2 connects to some other server. Check domain names, IPs, network routes, ISP, etc.

That was my first theory too.  But, it definitely connects to the correct VM - firewall shows traffic arriving and then being sent on to the expected internal IP.

The answer turned out to be "yes there are somethings that don't go into the main log"
I was able to capture it in the nginx error_log instead:
server {
  listen 443 default_server ssl;
  server_name api.example.com;
  ssl_certificate   /etc/ssl/example.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key   /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
  error_log logs/err.log debug;
}

You have to make sure that the /etc/nginx/logs/err.log file is created first - I did this in my Dockerfile.
